# Regex re.sub above a certain character count

Tags: python, regex

```
example = re.sub('「[^)]*」','', example)
```

I need to only replace things if "example" is above a certain amount of characters. I think I should be able to do it using modifiers, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using look aheads as

```
example = re.sub('(?=^.{5})「[^)]*」','', example)
```

- `(?=^.{5})` Look ahead assertion. Checks if the string contains `5` (for example) characters.

  *Here the replacement occures only if the the string is minimum of `5`characters*

**OR**

A generalised version can be written as

```
length = "5"
re.sub('(?=^.{' + length +'})[^)]*','', example)
```

**Example**

```
>>> example = "hello"
>>> re.sub('(?=^.{3})[^)]*','', example)
''
>>> example = "hello"
>>> re.sub('(?=^.{10})[^)]*','', example)
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def repl(matchobj):
    if len(matchobj.group(0))>5:
        return #something



example = re.sub('「[^)]*」',repl, example)
```

You can use function with `re.sub`.Based on length you can define your own function and return what you want.